# Taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7

I created a taxonomy vocabulary that groups all blogs with the specified taxonomy term. I mapped a menu link to this taxonomy term. When this menu link is accessed, I see all the blogs listed, but at the top of the page I see the vocabulary term shown in bold. I do not want this term on the page. How do I hide the term? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Drupal is the site built on?

Comment: Drupal 7 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was actually very simple. I logged in as the user that created the vocabulary and the vocabulary-URL mapping, clicked on the menu link that linked to the taxonomy vocabulary page, the page loads with view & edit tabs, clicking edit will let you change the title of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could try tracking down from which theme function or template file it is coming from and removing it there. The [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) modules can probably help you with that. Hiding it via CSS may be acceptable as well since it's only a small piece of html code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the content type > Manage Display > Hide the term reference.

Comment: gilzero, the term reference is already hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not immediately sure why the term is displayed as it is, but what I always do myself, is use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to override the taxonomy display. Panels being a complicated tool, one could think it's a bit overkill to use for something as simple as removing this little piece of text; but the extra control you get this way is well worth learning. Here are videos demonstrating the use of the [Page managar and Panels](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager).